# django models filter ordering

Tags: python, django, orm

I do such a thing:

```
Player.objects.distinct().filter(Q(game1_set=game) | Q(game2_set=game))
```

It returns all players, that played `game`. I want the result to be orderd, like in filter: `game1_set` first and then `game2_set`. But it's not so. It's orderd by `id`.

Also, I need a `QuerySet` result, so, merging two lists is not an option.

Here is a `models.py` for better understanding:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    game1_set = models.ManyToManyField('Game', verbose_name='players1')
    game2_set = models.ManyToManyField('Game', verbose_name='players2')

class Game(models.Model):
    # some fields here
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding `.order_by('game1_set','game2_set')`

```
Player.objects.distinct().filter(Q(game1_set=game) | Q(game2_set=game)).order_by('game1_set','game2_set')
```

Comment: It orders players, but it does not do what i whant to do. Thanks anyway